# What methods are called after DidSelectAnnotationView/DidDeSelectAnnotationView in MapView in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm working on a Xamarin iOS project and have a view with a MapView that contains modified MKAnnotations and implements IMKMapViewDelegate.

The view shows a map with a few annotations on the map. Tapping an annotation displays a callout bubble with extra info.

The view also has an overlay view at the bottom of the screen which can be swiped up to display detailed info. The problem is that when an annotation is selected or deselected, the overlay view moves half way up the screen. The annotation selection event calls the methods DidSelectAnnotationView/DidDeselectAnnotationView but the movement of the overlay is triggered after those calls and I cannot hit any break points in any of my code when this event occurs.

So the question is, which iOS methods get called after DidSelectAnnotationView and DidDeselectAnnotationView which could be causing my issue?
The code below reverts the overlay back to its original position but with an obvious UI glitch.

```
       [Export("mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:")]
        public void DidSelectAnnotationView(MKMapView mapView, MKAnnotationView annotationView)
        {
            DelayedOverlayReset();
        }

        [Export("mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView:")]
        public void DidDeselectAnnotationView(MKMapView mapView, MKAnnotationView annotationView)
        {
            DelayedOverlayReset();
        }

        private async Task DelayedOverlayReset()
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(150);
            });

            _overlayView?.SetUpOverlayMinPosition();
        }
```

I can share more code but its work related so I need to anonymise it. Happy to provide further detail or answer questions as necessary.

EDIT overlay view:

```
namespace Touch.Views.Detail
{
    [Register("DetailsOverlayView")]
    public sealed class DetailsOverlayView : UIView
    {
        private const float OverlayDragBarWidth = 56.0f;
        private const float OverlayDragBarTopPadding = 20.0f;
        private const float OverlayDragBarHeight = 6.0f;
        private const float OverlayDragBarBottomPadding = 18.0f;
        private const float CornerRadius = 18.0f;
        private const float ScoreImageWidth = 60.0f;
        private const float IconImageWidth = 16.0f;
        private const float ShadowOpacity = 0.15f;
        private const float ShadowRadius = 10.0f;
        private const float ShadowOffsetWidth = 0f;
        private const float ShadowOffsetHeight = 10.0f;
        private const float ViewAnchorMidPoint = 0.5f;
        private const float ImageDurationToLabelGap = 30;
        private const float AddressIconWidthAndPadding = 18.0f;

        private const double StartingOverlayAnimationSpeed = 0.3;
        private const double AnimationSpeedThreshold = 1.3;

        private const string DistanceImageName = "icon_map";
        private const string DurationImageName = "icon_clock";

        private static readonly TextStyle Heading3SemiBold = TextStyle.Heading3.SemiBold.BrandSecondary;
        private static readonly TextStyle BodyRegularCaption = TextStyle.Body.Regular.TextCaption;
        private readonly DetailOverlayDisplayData? _displayData;
        private readonly double _maxPosition;
        private readonly double _minPosition;

        private readonly UIView? _parentView;
        private readonly ElementLinksViewModel? _ActionViewModel;

        private NSLayoutConstraint? _dragBarBottomPadding;
        private UIView? _overlayDragBarView;
        private UIView? _overlayHeaderAndContentView;
        private UIPanGestureRecognizer? _panGestureRecognizer;
        private UIScrollView? _scrollView;
        private UIStackView? _stackView;
        private double _startingPosition;

        public NSLayoutConstraint? OverlayHeight;

        public DetailsOverlayView(DetailOverlayDisplayData displayData, ElementLinksViewModel action,
            UIView parentView)
        {
            _parentView = parentView;
            _displayData = displayData;
            _ActionViewModel = action;

            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            ClipsToBounds = false;
            Layer.CornerRadius = CornerRadius;
            Hidden = true;

            Layer.ShadowOpacity = ShadowOpacity;
            Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(ShadowOffsetWidth, -ShadowOffsetHeight);
            Layer.ShadowRadius = ShadowRadius;

            SetUp();

            var headerView = new DetailHeaderView();
            headerView.SetUp(displayData, _scrollView!, _stackView!, parentView);

            CreateContentPanel();
            SetUpOverlayConstraints();

            _minPosition = Math.Round(parentView.Frame.Height - GetHeaderHeight(displayData, parentView.Bounds.Width));
            _maxPosition = 0;
        }

        public void SetUpOverlayStartingPosition()
        {
            if (_parentView == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Center = new CGPoint(Center.X, _parentView.Frame.Height);
            Layer.AnchorPoint = new CGPoint(ViewAnchorMidPoint, 0f);
            Hidden = false;

            SetOverlayPosition(StartingOverlayAnimationSpeed, _minPosition, CornerRadius, true);

            _overlayDragBarView!.Hidden = false;
        }

        public void SetUpOverlayMinPosition()
        {    
            SetOverlayPosition(0.01, _minPosition, CornerRadius, true);

            _overlayDragBarView!.Hidden = false;
        }

        private void SetUp()
        {
            _overlayDragBarView = new UIView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray,
                ClipsToBounds = true
            };
            _overlayDragBarView.RoundCorners(ViewCornerStyle.All, OverlayDragBarHeight / 2);

            _overlayHeaderAndContentView = new UIView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                ClipsToBounds = true
            };

            AddSubview(_overlayDragBarView);
            AddSubview(_overlayHeaderAndContentView);

            _panGestureRecognizer = new UIPanGestureRecognizer(PanOverlayView);
            _panGestureRecognizer.CancelsTouchesInView = true;
            AddGestureRecognizer(_panGestureRecognizer);

            var (outerScrollView, _, innerStackView) =
                _overlayHeaderAndContentView!.CreateScrollViewWithFooterAndStackView(UIColor.White);
            _stackView = innerStackView;
            _stackView.LayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true;

            _scrollView = outerScrollView;
            _scrollView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
            _scrollView.Bounces = true;
            _scrollView.SetContentOffset(CGPoint.Empty, true);
            _scrollView.Scrolled += ScrollViewOnScrolled;
        }

        private void CreateContentPanel()
        {
            var view = new UIView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
                ClipsToBounds = true
            };

            var contentStackView = new UIStackView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical,
                LayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true,
                Spacing = StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall,
                DirectionalLayoutMargins =
                    new NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(0, StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall, StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall,
                        StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall)
            };

            _stackView!.AddArrangedSubview(view);
            view.AddSubview(contentStackView);

            NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(new[]
            {
                view.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.Superview.LeadingAnchor),
                view.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.Superview.TrailingAnchor),

                contentStackView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.TopAnchor),
                contentStackView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.BottomAnchor),
                contentStackView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.LeadingAnchor),
                contentStackView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(view.TrailingAnchor)
            });

            var milesTimePanel = SetUpDistanceAndDurationLayout();

            var ActionView = ElementLinksView.Create();
            _ActionViewModel!.Alignment = Alignment.Center;
            ActionView.SetUp(_ActionViewModel);

            var scoreSummaryView = new ScoreSummaryView();
            scoreSummaryView.SetUp(_displayData!.ScoreSummary);

            contentStackView.AddArrangedSubview(milesTimePanel);
            contentStackView.AddArrangedSubview(ActionView);
            contentStackView.AddArrangedSubview(scoreSummaryView);

            contentStackView.SetCustomSpacing(StyleGuideDimens.PaddingMedium, milesTimePanel);

            milesTimePanel.LayoutIfNeeded();
            view.LayoutIfNeeded();
            _stackView.LayoutIfNeeded();
        }

        private void SetUpOverlayConstraints()
        {
            NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(new[]
            {
                _overlayDragBarView!.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(CenterXAnchor),
                _overlayDragBarView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(TopAnchor, OverlayDragBarTopPadding),
                _overlayDragBarView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(OverlayDragBarWidth),
                _overlayDragBarView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(OverlayDragBarHeight),
                _dragBarBottomPadding = _overlayHeaderAndContentView!.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(
                    _overlayDragBarView!.BottomAnchor, OverlayDragBarBottomPadding),

                _overlayHeaderAndContentView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(BottomAnchor),
                _overlayHeaderAndContentView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(LeadingAnchor),
                _overlayHeaderAndContentView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(TrailingAnchor)
            });

            _overlayDragBarView.LayoutIfNeeded();
            _overlayHeaderAndContentView.LayoutIfNeeded();
        }

        private void PanOverlayView(UIPanGestureRecognizer gesture)
        {
            if (_parentView == null || OverlayHeight == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (gesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
            {
                _startingPosition = Frame.Y;
            }

            var scrollOffset = _scrollView!.ContentOffset.Y;
            var velocity = gesture.VelocityInView(_parentView);
            var y = _parentView.Frame.GetMinY();

            var newPos = _startingPosition + gesture.TranslationInView(_parentView).Y;

            if (newPos >= _minPosition)
            {
                SetOverlayPosition(0, _minPosition);
            }
            else if (newPos <= _maxPosition)
            {
                SetOverlayPosition(0, _maxPosition, 0, true, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                //Scroll the scrollView content to the top
                _scrollView!.SetContentOffset(CGPoint.Empty, true);

                if (scrollOffset <= 0)
                {
                    Frame = new CGRect(0, newPos, Frame.Width, Frame.Height);
                }
            }

            if (gesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
            {
                var duration = velocity.Y < 0 ? (y - _maxPosition) / -velocity.Y : _minPosition - (y / velocity.Y);
                duration = duration > AnimationSpeedThreshold ? 1 : duration;

                if (velocity.Y > 0)
                {
                    if (scrollOffset <= 0)
                    {
                        //Scroll the scrollView content to the top
                        _scrollView!.SetContentOffset(CGPoint.Empty, true);

                        _scrollView!.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
                        SetOverlayPosition(duration, _minPosition);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _scrollView!.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
                    SetOverlayPosition(duration, _maxPosition, 0, true, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetOverlayPosition(double animationDuration, double position, float cornerRadius = CornerRadius,
            bool dragBarVisibility = false, float dragBarBottomPadding = 18.0f)
        {
            Animate(animationDuration, () =>
            {
                Frame = new CGRect(0, position, Frame.Width, Frame.Height);
                _overlayDragBarView!.Hidden = dragBarVisibility;
                _dragBarBottomPadding!.Constant = dragBarBottomPadding;
            });

            AnimateCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
        }

        private void ScrollViewOnScrolled(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var scrollOffset = _scrollView!.ContentOffset.Y;

            if (scrollOffset >= -1 && _panGestureRecognizer != null)
            {
                _scrollView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        #region Helper Methods

        private void AnimateCornerRadius(float cornerRadius) =>
            Animate(0.1, () => { Layer.CornerRadius = cornerRadius; });

        private UIView SetUpDistanceAndDurationLayout()
        {
            var containerView = new UIView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                ClipsToBounds = false
            };

            if (_displayData == null)
            {
                return containerView;
            }

            var imageDistance = new UIImageView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                Image = UIImage.FromBundle(DistanceImageName),
                ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            };

            var imageDuration = new UIImageView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                Image = UIImage.FromBundle(DurationImageName),
                ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            };

            var distanceDurationWrapperView = new UIView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                ClipsToBounds = true
            };

            var stackView = new UIStackView
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal,
                Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Fill,
                Spacing = 0
            };
            containerView.AddSubview(stackView);

            stackView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(containerView.TopAnchor).Active = true;
            stackView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(containerView.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
            stackView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(containerView.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
            stackView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(containerView.TrailingAnchor, 0).Active = true;

            var distanceLabel = _displayData.TotalMiles.CreateLabel(BodyRegularCaption, ElementMargins.None(),
                UITextAlignment.Left);
            var durationLabel = _displayData.TotalJourneyTime.CreateLabel(BodyRegularCaption, ElementMargins.None(),
                UITextAlignment.Left);

            stackView.AddArrangedSubview(distanceDurationWrapperView);
            distanceDurationWrapperView.AddSubview(imageDistance);
            distanceDurationWrapperView.AddSubview(distanceLabel);
            distanceDurationWrapperView.AddSubview(imageDuration);
            distanceDurationWrapperView.AddSubview(durationLabel);

            imageDistance.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(IconImageWidth).Active = true;
            imageDistance.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(IconImageWidth).Active = true;

            imageDuration.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(IconImageWidth).Active = true;
            imageDuration.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(IconImageWidth).Active = true;

            imageDistance.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceDurationWrapperView.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;
            imageDistance.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceDurationWrapperView.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;

            distanceLabel.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceDurationWrapperView.TopAnchor).Active = true;
            distanceLabel.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceDurationWrapperView.BottomAnchor, 0).Active = true;
            distanceLabel.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(imageDistance.TrailingAnchor,
                StyleGuideDimens.PaddingExtraSmall).Active = true;

            imageDuration.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceDurationWrapperView.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;
            imageDuration.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceLabel.TrailingAnchor, ImageDurationToLabelGap)
                .Active = true;

            durationLabel.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceDurationWrapperView.TopAnchor).Active = true;
            durationLabel.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceDurationWrapperView.BottomAnchor, 0).Active = true;
            durationLabel.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(imageDuration.TrailingAnchor,
                StyleGuideDimens.PaddingExtraSmall).Active = true;
            durationLabel.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(distanceDurationWrapperView.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;

            distanceDurationWrapperView.LayoutIfNeeded();
            containerView.LayoutIfNeeded();
            stackView.LayoutIfNeeded();

            return containerView;
        }

        public static nfloat GetHeaderHeight(JourneyDetailOverlayDisplayData displayData, nfloat availableWidth)
        {
            //Left padding, left score panel padding, score panel width, right padding
            var totalAvailableWidth = availableWidth - (StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall +
                StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall + ScoreImageWidth + StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall);

            var headerString = new NSString(displayData.JourneyDate);
            var distance = new NSString(displayData.TotalMiles);
            var duration = new NSString(displayData.TotalJourneyTime);

            var sizeOfHeader = headerString.GetCalculatedSizeOfString(FontStyle.SemiBold.GetFont(Heading3SemiBold.Size),
                totalAvailableWidth);

            var (sizeOfStartAddress, sizeOfEndAddress) = GetAddressPanelHeights(displayData, availableWidth);

            var sizeOfDistance = distance.GetCalculatedSizeOfString(FontStyle.Regular.GetFont(BodyRegularCaption.Size),
                totalAvailableWidth);

            var sizeOfDuration = duration.GetCalculatedSizeOfString(FontStyle.Regular.GetFont(BodyRegularCaption.Size),
                totalAvailableWidth);

            var distanceHeight = sizeOfDistance.Height > IconImageWidth
                ? sizeOfDistance.Height
                : IconImageWidth;

            var durationHeight = sizeOfDuration.Height > IconImageWidth
                ? sizeOfDuration.Height
                : IconImageWidth;

            var distanceDurationPanelHeight = distanceHeight > durationHeight ? distanceHeight : durationHeight;

            return OverlayDragBarTopPadding
                   + OverlayDragBarHeight
                   + OverlayDragBarBottomPadding
                   + sizeOfHeader.Height
                   + StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall
                   + sizeOfStartAddress.Height
                   + StyleGuideDimens.PaddingExtraSmall
                   + sizeOfEndAddress.Height
                   + StyleGuideDimens.PaddingMedium
                   + distanceDurationPanelHeight
                   + StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall;
        }

        public static (CGSize startAddressHeight, CGSize endAddressHeight) GetAddressPanelHeights(
            JourneyDetailOverlayDisplayData displayData, nfloat availableWidth)
        {
            //Left padding, Address icon width and padding, left score panel padding, score panel width, right padding
            var totalAvailableWidth = availableWidth - (StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall + AddressIconWidthAndPadding +
                StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall + ScoreImageWidth + StyleGuideDimens.PaddingSmall);

            var startAddress = new NSString(displayData.JourneyStartAddress);
            var endAddress = new NSString(displayData.JourneyEndAddress);

            var sizeOfStartAddress = startAddress.GetCalculatedSizeOfString(
                FontStyle.Regular.GetFont(BodyRegularCaption.Size),
                totalAvailableWidth);

            var sizeOfEndAddress = endAddress.GetCalculatedSizeOfString(
                FontStyle.Regular.GetFont(BodyRegularCaption.Size),
                totalAvailableWidth);

            return (sizeOfStartAddress, sizeOfEndAddress);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you haven't set constraints correctly or have modified the frame of your overlay and then when the layout process runs, it is being moved back to where the layout engine thinks it should be.  What does `SetUpOverlayMinPosition();` do?

Comment: SetUpOverlayMinPosition calls the methods that animate the overlay view to its normal lowered position. So in the case above, it reverts the undesired movement up of the overlay view. But you see this glitchy movement up and back down.

Comment: How is the overlay positioned?  Are you using constraints? Views moving unexpectedly are normally not having correct constraints or manipulating the location of views directiy rather than manipulating the constraints.

Comment: I've added the constraints code above. Does this help?

Comment: Kind of; you seem to have a "drag bar" for positioning the overlay. How does this work?  You aren't keeping a reference to the overlay to constraint so that you can modify it. If you are modifying the `frame` directly at any point you will get the behaviour you are describing when autolayout runs and resets everything based on the constraints.

Comment: The drag bar is at the top of the overlay view allowing that view to be dragged up to occupy the whole screen. I can check on Monday if frame gets modified at all. Might keeping a reference somewhere in those constraints help? Is there a way to debug auto layout?

Comment: You need a reference to the relevant constraint so that you can modify it in the drag gesture recognizer. If you don’t have a reference you are almost certainly changing a view frame directly which will cause the problem you see

Comment: Hi Paul. I've checked on our code sharing policy and found out its fine if anonymised so I've added the full overlay view class, just slightly editted. We are definitely doing bits with the Frame. Hopefully with this extra info you may be able to suggest a solution? Btw, i'm a graduate and this is my first time working on iOS ui stuff so really appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, you are setting the `Frame` to change the overlay view's position. You must not do that. As soon as anything triggers an autolayout (such as selecting or deselecting an annotation) the view will be repositioned to where the constraints say it should be. You need to modify the constraints as you do for the  padding constraint.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Would you mind suggesting an answer showing the required code changes? Thanks so much for looking at this.

Comment: As Paulw11 said, the Frame is changing the position of the overlay view, you can try using AbsoluteLayout to see if that's the problem.